# Sufficient condition for finite Expectation

Tags: integration, probability-theory, expectation

In the lecture the lecturer wrote:

"Assume that for a random variable $X$ it holds that $X \geq 0$ or $X \in L^1$. Then $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$."

I can understand (or partially understand) why integrability implies finiteness of expectation. But why should non-negativity imply that the expectation exists?

Did I got something wrong?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Of course non-negativity does not imply finite expected value. Consider discrete distribution: $P(X=k)=\frac{1}{k(k+1)} $ for $k=1,2,...$

Comment: I did not think about this example but I could imagine that non-negativity does not imply finiteness of expectation. So do you probably know what he could have meant with it?

Is $X \in L^1$ enough for finiteness? Or could he probably meant $X \geq 0 $ AND $X \in L^1$?

Or could you tell me what the "usual" conditions for finiteness are?

Comment: @user146358 Those conditions are exactly the condition needed to apply Fubini. Does this tell you anything?

Comment: $X \in L^1$ implies finite expected value. If that's all you need then condition $X \ge 0$ is unnecessary.

Comment: Oh ok, so if we have $X \geq 0$ and $X \in L^1$, we have finite expected value (because of $X \in L^1$) and moreover we can apply Fubini, that is, we can change the ordering of integrals?

If we only have $X \geq 0$ we can apply Fubini but we cannot guarantee that the expectation is finite. And if we only have $X \in L^1$, then we have finite expectation and we can apply Fubini?

Comment: Does he use the finiteness?  With the usual definition, the expectation is defined if either $X\geq 0$ (or $X\leq 0$) or $X\in L^1$.  So, perhaps he just wanted to assume that $\mathbb{E}[X]$ exists.